# jquery function in cakephp2

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp-2.0

I'm beginner on both jquery and cakephp. I have tried to run a jquery function into my page index  and It doesn't work.
this function nest a ticker in my principal page index from another page called ticker.
cakephp path used are like that SessionModels/ticker.ctp and SessionModels/index.ctp.

when I run my page `ticker.ctp` alone, it runs without a problem displaying a ticker but when I have tried to nest it in a `<div id="ticker"> </div>` with my jquery function in `index.ctp`, it doesn't do anything .
this is my javascript/ jquery function :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" > function ticker(){

    $.ajax ({
        type:'GET',
        url:'/SessionModels/ticker/',
        success:function(e){
            $('#ticker').html(e);
        },
        complete : function(e){
            setTimeout ("ticker()", 3000);
        }
    });

}

$(document).ready(function(){
ticker();
});</script>
```

I have added as I have seen also in cakephp tutorial this code in my controller

```
public $helpers = array('Js');
```

this is the content of my ticker.ctp

```
    <marquee >
<?php foreach ($sessions as $session): ?>
<span style="color:#333333; font-size:12px; font-weight:bolder; font-family:Arial; vertical-align: text-top;"><?php echo $session['Dictionnary']['ticker']; ?>
</span>
        <?php echo $session['SessionModel']['_open']; ?>
        <?php echo $session['SessionModel']['_close']; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</marquee>
```

and this is the content of my controller:

```
    class SessionModelsController extends Controller {

    public $helpers = array('Js');
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public function index() {
        $this->set('sessions', $this->SessionModel->find('all', array('contain' => 'Dictionnary.stock_name')));

    }
    public function ticker() {
        $this->set('sessions', $this->SessionModel->find('all', array('contain' => 'Dictionnary.ticker')));
    }
}
```

as I have said , it works perfectly without a problem but nesting the ticker.ctp in index.ctp is the problem.
thank you for the help

Comment: provide your view, do you have more than 1 element with the id ticker ?

Comment: If you check the 'network' tab in firebug or Chrome webinspector, can you see that your function is retrieving something?

Comment: exactly it retrieves nothing , I have the server code 304 . @thaJeztah

Comment: Can you also provide the code of the SessionModels for the ticker action? Maybe you're injecting the layout of cake without wanting to do so.

Comment: @LuisTellez no it is only one element which is <div id="ticker"></div> ! I cannot attach a print screen here unfortunately to show you what I have .

Comment: @nuns I haven't understood what I should feed you exactely ? the view part of ticker.ctp is 
that 
<marquee >
<?php foreach ($sessions as $session): ?>
<span style="color:#333333; font-size:12px; font-weight:bolder; font-family:Arial; vertical-align: text-top;"><?php echo $session['Dictionnary']['ticker']; ?>
</span>
        <?php echo $session['SessionModel']['_open']; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</marquee>
and as I have I said when I run it alone it works without a problem
do you need more ?

Comment: Btw, there's no need to put the Js helper on your controller if you're not actually using it (at least not on the view you put here)

Comment: What I meant is: you have a SessionModelsController somewhere, and you must have some actions there, like `public function index() {}` and `public function ticker()` action. Can you update your question with that code?

Comment: @nuns I have made the update to my question as you have suggested .

Comment: For debugging purposes: can you add an `echo "hello";` on the first line of the ticker action an see if firebug or Chrome webinspector gets that back? If not, the jquery function is not been called (to check that put an `alert("hello");` before the ajax call

Comment: @nuns 
echo "hello"; 
runs and is displayed without a problem !!
but although the script is displayed in my firebug, alerts doesn't work at all!!!

Comment: What @thaJeztah is telling you in his answer will probably work since we're debuggin on the same path. If not, try adding the ticker function inside the `$(document).ready` declaration, like `$(document).ready(function() {function ticker() {alert("hello");} ticker(); });` and see if the alert is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Http Status Code 304 'not modified' may indicate that your browser is using a cached version of the request instead of retrieving new data. This is probably caused by 'cache' headers being sent by your server.

jQuery.ajax() has a 'cache' option that prevents browser caching for the AJAX request and *forces* reloading the page by adding a random time stamp to each request.

Add the 'cache' option to your .ajax options and set it to 'false' to use it;

```
function ticker(){
    $.ajax ({
        type:'GET',
        url:'/SessionModels/ticker/',
        cache:false,
        success:function(e){
            $('#ticker').html(e);
        },
        complete : function(e){
            setTimeout(ticker, 3000);
        }
    });
}
```

Read the documentation here [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

To check if it the ticker() function is actually running, try temporarily changing it to this;

```
function ticker(){
    alert('tick');
    setTimeout(ticker, 3000);
}
```

I tested this in my situation and it works without problems, however, you should make sure that jQuery is loaded *before* this. Since you're using this code inside a *View*, it's possible you're loading jQuery afterwards (just before the closing `</body>` tag)

A better option is to use the buffer of the JsHelper and output the buffered script in you layout;

```
/**
 * JsHelper will append this block to the $(document).ready()
 */
$script = "
        function ticker() {
            $.ajax ({
                type:'GET',
                url:'/timeline/qty_breakdown/',
                cache:false,
                success:function(e){
                    $('#ticker').html(e);
                },
                complete : function(e){
                    setTimeout (ticker, 3000);
                }
            });
        }

        ticker();
";

$this->Js->buffer($script);
```

Then, inside your layout (just before the closing `</body>` tag):

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

This will automatically wrap your script inside a $(document).ready(...)

Comment: It still doesnt work @thaJeztah , and I still have 304 code and no XHR request !!! I have made some update to my principal post if you want to check it :(

Comment: Are you seeing errors in your console? Also, it may be better to not to use a string for the setTimeout(), although this probably is not the problem (I'll add some more to my answer)

Comment: I have modified my script with  setTimeout(ticker, 3000);
and I have made several alert in the beginning of the code and its end !
although the script is displayed in my firebug, alerts doesn't work!!!

Comment: I just tested this code in my browser and it works correctly in my situation. Again, check if jQuery is being loaded (and if it is loaded before this script). Check your firebug console, is it showing errors? I added an example to use the JsHelper, which allows you to output the script in your layout.